# How can something like a Arri 20,000 watt light bulb handle so much power?

Tags: power, power-consumption, high-power

I'm curious to know how can something like the Arri bulb or any bulb near that wattage range can handle so much power? The filaments is thicker so is that why? As regular ligh bulbs would burn around and break.

As i research more about bulb bases i am starting to think one aspect is the diameter of the contact point. Is thia true? Higher voltage application use a mogul screws while an average bulb uses the E27. This is just a guess. Trying to make connections.

Comment: Much bigger than E27, ceramic socket, welded contacts and some other improvements. Check out lamptech.co.uk for lots of details.

Comment: Posting URL/images/or some info of what you are talking about helps a lot in getting decent answers.

Answer (score 1):

There are several design features that determine power capability of a given incandescent bulb. They are all related to the heat that must be dissipated (20,000) watts and the temperature that the bulb can withstand.

The most obvious factor is the size of the glass bulb. A larger glass surface, allows more more heat to transferred to the surrounding air at a given temperature difference between the glass and the air. If the glass can withstand a higher temperature, more heat can be dissipated. Quartz glass can withstand a higher temperature than ordinary glass, so a given size quartz bulb can dissipate more heat than an ordinary bulb of the same size.

If the bulb can operate at a higher temperature, the filament can also, but it must be capable of a higher temperature. Including in the bulb a small amount of a halogen element like bromine or iodine keeps the tungsten element from deteriorating and depositing a metal coating on the inside of the bulb. That makes the filament last longer at a higher temperature and helps the bulb clear to allow light and heat to pass through the glass.

The base must be constructed to withstand a higher temperature and current. Higher current causes additional heating in the electrical conductors and connections. A higher electrical connection surface area minimizes the additional heating.

The 20,000 watt bulb shown below has an overall length of about 560 mm (22 in.). The diameter of the glass bulb is about 99 mm (3.9 in.). The space between the pins is about 38 mm (1.5 in.). The pin diameter is about 11 mm (.44 in.).

Note the long base designed to keep the hot bulb away from the supporting fixture.

[image]